# Exporting random points inside polygon as coordinates with lat/lon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, point, export, latitude-longitude

I have created a points layer in QGIS using `Vector > Research Tools > Random Points Inside Polygon`.

However, I would like to export the points as a GeoJSON file where each point has a coordinate (lat and lon) value.

So far the attribute table only shows the `"id"` for the point. Is there a way to do this in QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click the layer and choose Export->"Save objects as" down in the context menu (fourth entry from the bottom in my QGIS 3.28), and choose GeoJSON as the export format. Choose WGS84 (EPSG:4326) as output CRS.

The GeoJSON will have the coordinates contained.

See the QGIS documentation at [Creating new layers from an existing layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#general-saveas) for more details.